# Where can I download the JetBrains JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I'm looking for the JetBrains JDK, I can't find it. So, where is the official download page for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The download page is located at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/JBR/JetBrains+Runtime

The Bintray url this links to is https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jbr (it used to be https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/)

On the Bintray page for the JDK for your platform, the actual downloads are hiding under the **Files** tab:

[image: Download list]

Comment: I think when it takes you less than a minute to find the answer to your own question ... then maybe maybe A) you didnt do proper research before asking B) there is not much point in keeping this question around in the first place

Comment: Still the question itself is off-topic; as asking about a off-site resource. So why put up a clearly off-topic question in the first place?

Comment: @GhostCat Clearly, to annoy people like you and to help me and others looking for this information.

Comment: I give this answer a thumbs up. It has certainly helped me find what I want so you all butthurt people should stop bitching about every little thing.